# Chrome shows all media connected with custom properties through URL but Safari doesn't load them

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari

When you are using custom properties with background-image - Safari interprets image's url another way, for example:

[image]
*Chrome shows all images, but Safari logs "not allowed to load local resource*

Another example:
[image]
*Chrome doesn't show all images, but Safari works well*

The problem is direction, I don't know why but when you using custom properties and set url for background image - safari add one step up in path to a file, another words add "."

I was trying to resolve this problem and just create another document with custom props only for Safari, when JS detects Safari it switches css document with custom props, but it also doesen't works well because safari starts to show images - dat's cool, but it doesn't refresh new new images when I turn on dark-mode (that's the reason I started all)

Also, you can find good example here: https://github.com/rudensergey/testChromeSafari

My project, where I stuck with this problem: https://github.com/rudensergey/darkroom

I expect next:
I have pseudo objects with images (I set them as background-image with URL), instead URL of background-image I use custom prop var(--pucture) for example

after that when I want to switch my website to the dark-theme JS rewrites custom prop () and new images apply to a webpage, but...

Comment: in my safari - both divs work

Comment: maybe there are some settings in browser which influence, but I can't recall that I was touching them. Thanks Dan

Comment: check your file permissions on the media?

Comment: browser has all permissions. I just check devTools in Safari and see path of custom prop - safari has as the same path to file as chrome has but Safari jump up in direction, I mean:

--picture(url("./media/file")
background-image: var(--picture);

chrome is looking in: desktop/project/media/file
safari is looking in: desktop/media/file

that's a problem

Answer (score 0):

i changed your `:root` to this:

```
:root {
    /* Images are in the same directory */

    /* this path works in Chrome */
    --path-to-image-one: url(../media/1.png);
    /* this path works in Safari */
    --path-to-image-two: url(../media/2.jpg);
}
```

and it worked on both for me - see screen shot

[image]

Comment: Now set as you show:

  /* this path works in Chrome */
    --path-to-image-one: url(../media/1.png);
    /* this path works in Safari */
    --path-to-image-two: url(../media/2.jpg);

It doesn't work

Comment: i dont understand your comment - i set it as you said in my response above and it works great - this is not an issue with safari or chrome or html or css or javascript - your local environment is overriding something